# How to take the reference of multiple subnets in route_table_association in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-aws-modules

```
resource "aws_subnet" "VPC_Public_Subnets" {
vpc_id = aws_vpc.Oracle_VPC_TF_Block.id
for_each = local.subnets.public

availability_zone = each.value.zone
cidr_block = each.value.cidr

tags = {
  Name = each.value.name
  Tier = each.value.tier
}
```

}

This is how created the subnets. This block is creating 2 subnets. Now, I want the `subnet_id` of each of the 2 subnets that will be used in `route_table_association`.

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "Private_Route_Table_App1_Db1_Association" {
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.VPC_Public_Subnets.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.Private_Route_Table_App1_Db1.id
}
```

Now, the problem is what we will the value of `subnet_id`. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've used `for_each` for subnets, you have to use it for route table associations as well:

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "Private_Route_Table_App1_Db1_Association" {
  for_each  = aws_subnet.VPC_Public_Subnets
  subnet_id = each.value.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.Private_Route_Table_App1_Db1.id
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how? Because we need the subnet_id. I am looking for how can I get the subnet_id in for_each loop in route_table association.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta I already provided the answer on how to do it.

Comment: oh, I thought it was my code. No problem thanks. I will look into it.